# UICollection cells do not update, when changing value on one of them

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, swift5

Basically, i have a collection view with 6 cells, cells are with textfield and some checkboxes, what i have to do is, changing text on one of the cells, text has to change on all the others.

How do i do that?

[image]

P.S

Now, if i change value in first cell, it only applies on odd cell, not effecting even ones, and same for even cells.

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: Individual cells should never know about each other. Have each cell manipulate its part of the data model, and redraw the collection when the model changes.